# Unable to connect to Vagrant (ubuntu/trusty64) from host machine via port forwarding

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, vagrant, iptables

I have set up a Vagrant box with Ubuntu 14.04, node.js, npm, mongodb, forever, deployd and express. I forwarded the host port 8080 to guest port 80, and have a node server in the guest machine listening on port 80.

When I visit `http://localhost:8080` in my browser, I expect to see the output from my node server ("Hello World") but instead I get no response from the browser.

From inside the guest machine, when I attempt to curl, I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`.

From the host machine, when I attempt to curl, I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

I have tried allowing all incoming web traffic by modifying the iptables using `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`, and have saved those settings and restarted the machine using `vagrant reload`. That did not resolve the issue.

My Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
end
```

My provisioning script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nodejs
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/lib/node_modules/
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y mongodb-10gen
npm install forever -g
npm install deployd -g
npm install express -g
mkdir /data
mkdir /data/db
rm -rf /var/www
ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
```

I am running `forever start server.js` to start up this sample node server:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(80);
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure the box is listening on port 8080? netstat -ntlp | grep 8080

Comment: @Tiago Yes, my host machine is listening on port 8080. However, my guest machine (Vagrant box) was _NOT_ listening on port 80, despite my node server telling it to do so. The problem was that I did not run the node server with `sudo`! *facepalm* Your suggestion helped me resolve this, so if you want to make that an answer I will accept. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad it helped. I've just created an answer. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your host is listening on port 8080:

```
$netstat -ntlp | grep 8080
```

Comment: Thanks again! It was not the host, but the guest machine that was not listening on port 80. Just had to use `sudo` when running the node server.